# Trying to inject $window into angular factory using typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am trying to inject $winow into my factory.

Here is my factory and class definition

```
 export interface IAuthToken {
 }

 export class AuthToken implements IAuthToken {
     storage: Storage;
     constructor(private $window: ng.IWindowService) {
        this.storage = this.$window.localStorage;
     }

    factory.$inject = ['$window'];
    function factory($window: ng.IWindowService): IAuthToken {
        return new AuthToken(this.$window);
    }

    angular
        .module('test')
        .factory('app.common.auth.AuthToken', factory);
}
```

When I debug the code the $window is always set to undefined. I have attempted to add the injection when registering the factory itself and I still get the $window as undefined?

```
function factory($window: ng.IWindowService): IAuthToken {
    return new AuthToken(this.$window);
}

angular
    .module('test')
    .factory('app.common.auth.AuthToken', ['$window',factory]);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That code makes little sense to me: the function creating an AuthToken is a function of AuthToken. So you need an AuthToken with a field of type $window in order to create an AuthToken with a $window. How could that work? Remove the factory function, and use `.service('app.common.auth.AuthToken', ['$window', AuthToken]);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there. You need to move your factory declarations outside of your `AuthToken` class and just below it. You could change to this:

```

```
export interface IAuthToken {}

export class AuthToken implements IAuthToken {

    static Id: string = 'app.common.auth.AuthToken';

    storage: Storage;
    constructor(private $window: ng.IWindowService) {
        this.storage = this.$window.localStorage;
    }
}

function factory($window: ng.IWindowService): IAuthToken {
    return new AuthToken($window);
}

angular
    .module('test')
    .factory(AuthToken.Id, ['$window', factory]);
```

```

Comment: This resolved one of the issues I had in the code, the additional issue was in the factory I had this.$window I moved the code and removed the this. from the $window and all worked.....Thanks

Comment: Wow, I missed that too. I copied your code and focused on the factory declaration. I've updated my code for others.